# C++ default move operation in "Effective Modern C++"

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, effective-c++

Item 17: Understand special member function generation.

1. Move operations are generated only for classed lacking
   explicitly declared move operation, copy operations, 
   or a destructor.
2. Now, when I refer to a move operation move-constructing
   or move-assigning a data member or base class, there
   is no guarantee that a move will actually take place.
   "Memberwise moves" are, in reality, more like memberwise
   move requests, because types that aren't move-enabled(...)
   will be "moved" via their copy operations.

However, I can not verify them on my environment.

```
// compiled
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
public:
    ~Base() {}
};
int main() {
    Base a, c;
    Base b(move(a));
    c = move(b);
    // explicitly destructor does not disable 
    // default move constuctor and move assignment operator
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    Base(Base& b) {}
    ~Base() {}
};
class Num {
private:
    Base b;
};
int main() {
    Num a, c;
    c = move(a); // passed
    Num b(move(c)); // error
    // explicitly Base::Base(Base& b) disable default move 
    // move conctructor. 
    // Num's default move constructor can not find any move
    // constructor for member object Base b, which lead to an 
    // error. Num's default move constructor does not "moved" 
    // Base b via their copy operations which is declared.
    return 0;
}
```

The first assertion might be vary from different environments, but the second one is almost wrong.
I am very confusing about it. 
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base {
public:
    ~Base() {}
};
```

Because `Base` has a user-declared destructor, it does not have a move constructor or move assignment operator at all.  The lines

```
Base b(move(a));
c = move(b);
```

actually call the copy constructor and copy assignment operator, respectively.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    Base(Base& b) {}
    ~Base() {}
};
class Num {
private:
    Base b;
};
```

Again, `Base` has no move constructor at all.  However, `Num` does have an implicitly-declared move constructor, since `Num` itself does not declare any special member functions.  However, it is implicitly defined as deleted, since the default definition would be ill-formed:

```
Num::Num(Num&& n) : b(std::move(n.b)) {}
// Cannot convert rvalue of type `Base` to `Base&`
// for the copy constructor to be called.
```

Note that the "move" of `b` *does* attempt to use the copy constructor, but it can't.